# What is the alternative for specflow.exe to generate html reports

Tags: mstest, specflow

I updated the specflow to 3.0 from 2.4 version to use its dependency injection feature and achieve parallel execution.

Parallel execution is working fine and I am getting trx file aswell but not able to generate classic HTML report using specflow. **Because specflow 3.0 is not providing .exe now.**

Is there any alternative fo this apart from using the Extent report.

**I just want to generate a classic HTML report from trx file**

Comment: You can use Extent Reports. I haven't used it but seen its pretty straightforward

Comment: Extent report generates the report during test execution. But I want to generate report from trx file which I get from the build pipeline after execution.

Comment: refer this link - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e634adf3-55aa-44f4-8cdd-ba6234bbcceb/how-to-make-mstest-based-tests-to-generate-html-report-after-tests-execution?forum=vsunittest

Comment: Thanks @Prany for your quick response. This worked for me☺. The generated report is not well structured but I can manage for now. I hope I will get the source code for this exe so that I can customize the report.

Comment: The code is here on github - https://github.com/NivNavick/trxer

Comment: I was here actually because I thought the question was if there is any alternative to Mono when generating the reports in Linux